# Undefined function or variable 'ndwt2'

Tags: matlab, wavelet-transform

I am doing a pansharpening fusion with one multi=spectral image and 1 Pan Image from LANDSAT 8.

The problem happens when I try to apply the AWLP algorithm from de Pansharpening Toolbox (author: Gemine Vinone et al) because the algorithm inside itself uses an 2D non-decimated wavelet transform function called `ndwt2`.

http://www.codeforge.com/read/255069/ndwt2.m__html <==== this file doesn't work for me

That function apparently was in the Wavelet Toolbox from MATLAB 2 or more years ago. I don't know how the algorithm works, so I need to know how to use `swt2`, `dwt2`, etc... to do the same operation that `ndwt2` did.

I've been searching on the whole web, even on the third Google page xD, but have not found a solution.

Comment: What release of Matlab are you using, Ruben?

Comment: Function introduced in 2010, removed in 2015 [(see release notes)](https://de.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/release-notes.html?searchHighlight=ndwt2&s_tid=doc_srchtitle). You can use [swt2](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/swt2.html) instead.